# Update UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin, refresh

I have two ViewControllers (ViewController A, ViewController B). Both are `UITableviewController`.

In ViewController A, I get the data from a database an put it to `List<string>`, so I can Display it.

I have a Navigationbar-button to go to ViewController B. In ViewController B I have List with additional Items. I can add the additional item to the database with a swipe action. This works.

When I go back to ViewController A I want to update my List, but I don't know how :(

I tried it with `ViewDidAppear`, but it does not work.

ViewController A:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    NavigationItem.Title = "Anwendungsfälle";

    // Hier geht es zum Hinzufügen der Anwendungsfeleder / -fälle oder Maßnahmen zum bestehenden Katalog

    this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add,
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Anwendungsfeld hinzufügen", "Wählen Sie eine Option aus", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

                // Hier geht es zur Vorgefertigten Bibliothek
                alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Aus Bibliothek hinzufügen", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (Action) =>
                {
                    AddAnFaViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AddAnFaViewController") as AddAnFaViewController;
                    controller.firmabereich = firmabereich;
                    controller.bereich = bereich;
                    controller.zieleid = zieleid;
                    controller.idafe = idafe;
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
                }));

                // Abbrechen Knopf
                alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Abbrechen", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine("Cancel clicked")));
                    PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
                }),
                true);

        var lines = new List<string>();


        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxx;Port=3306;database=xxxxb;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxx;charset=utf8"))
        {
            string query = $"SELECT DISTINCT Anwendungsfall FROM {firmabereich} WHERE IDAFE LIKE '{idafe}' ORDER BY Anwendungsfall ASC";
            string query2 = $"SELECT DISTINCT IDAFA FROM {firmabereich} WHERE IDAFE LIKE '{idafe}' ORDER BY Anwendungsfall ASC";
            string query3 = $"SELECT DISTINCT PrioAnFa, Anwendungsfall FROM {firmabereich} WHERE IDAFE LIKE '{idafe}' ORDER BY Anwendungsfall ASC";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection);
            MySqlCommand command3 = new MySqlCommand(query3, connection);
            connection.Open();

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    anwendungsfälle.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    anwendungsfälleid.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command3.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    prio.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }

        }

        TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 40f;
        TableView.ReloadData();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since reloading data affects the User Interface directly you need to reload data in GCD.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
       TableView.ReloadData();  
    }
```

GCD is Apple's multi threading concept; so take a time to understand how it works throughout the Application Life Cycle.

> [This could be the good introduction](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/understanding-threads-in-ios-5b8d7ab16f09)